# Reading from file error

Tags: java, file

i am having a problem reading from a file that looks like this:

```
1 7 21 16 44
2 7 21 16 45
3 7 21 16 46
4 7 21 16 47
5 7 21 16 48
6 7 21 16 49
7 7 21 16 50
```

I need to set each number to a specific variable in my program and then continue scanning for 365 times.each line represents (day of month sunriseHour sunriseMin  sunsetHour sunsetMin). I'm trying to read and set these variables so I can perform computations. I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 public void graph(Graphics page)
{
             int y = 0; //y-coordinate
    int sunriseX = 101;
    int sunsetX = 101;

    Scanner inputStream = null;
    try
    {
        inputStream = new Scanner("sunData.txt");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        System.out.println("or could not be opened.");
    }


    for (int i = 365; i <= 365; i++)
    {
        int day = inputStream.nextInt();

        setSunriseHour(inputStream.nextInt());
        setSunriseMin(inputStream.nextInt());
        setSunsetHour(inputStream.nextInt());
        setSunsetHour(inputStream.nextInt());
        inputStream.next();

        switch(sunriseHour)
        {
        case 4:
            y = 120;
            break;
        case 5:
            y = 180;
            break;
        case 6:
            y = 240;
            break;
        case 7:
            y = 300;
            break;
        case 8:
            y = 360;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("invalid time");
            break;

        }

        sunrisePoint = y + sunriseMin;
        page.drawOval (sunriseX, sunsetHour, 2, 2); // circle
                 sunriseX += 2;


        switch (sunsetHour)

        {
        case 16:
            y = 420;
            break;
        case 17:
            y = 480;
            break;
        case 18:
            y = 540;
            break;
        case 19:
            y = 600;
            break;
        case 20:
            y = 660;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("invalid time");
            break;
        }

        sunsetHour = y + sunsetMin;
        page.drawOval (sunsetX, sunsetHour, 2, 2); // circle
        sunsetX += 2;

    } //ends for loop
```

Comment: The problem is here `inputStream.next();`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. actually when I remove that line I still get the same erros...can't figure it out :/

Comment: Look at answer. Let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: What is meaning of this line `for (int i = 365; i <= 365; i++)`?

Comment: the file has 365 lines, i need it to do everything in the loop for each line in the file. the solution you gave me unfortunately doesn't work...:/

Comment: you need to start the for-loop at 0. But I would suggest to replace it with a while loop which reads till the end of time - since there is a day column....

Comment: Your pasted exception cuts off the most interesting line (the line in your source code).

Comment: Try to print "day", so if you get an exception you know in which line it is.

Answer (score 2):

Always check for next item before getting it.

```
while (inputStream.hasNext()) {

    int day = inputStream.nextInt();

    setSunriseHour(inputStream.nextInt());
    setSunriseMin(inputStream.nextInt());
    setSunsetHour(inputStream.nextInt());
    setSunsetHour(inputStream.nextInt());

    ....
}
```

You can look for other methods of [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#method_summary) class as well that is more specific to value type, such as [Scanner#hasNextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29)

```
while (inputStream.hasNextInt()) {
   int day = inputStream.nextInt();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
        try
        {
          Scanner inputStream = new Scanner("sunData.txt");
        }
```

instead of:

```
    Scanner inputStream = null;
        try
        {
          inputStream = new Scanner("sunData.txt");
        }
```

Comment: that does not work, inputStream wont be available outside the try.